# Spring Integration - @Filter discardChannel and/or throwExceptionOnRejection being ignored?

Tags: java-8, spring-integration

I have a java DSL based spring integration (`spring-integration-java-dsl:1.0.1.RELEASE`) flow which puts messages through a `Filter` to filter out certain messages. The `Filter` component works okay in terms of filtering out unwanted messages.

Now, I would like to set either a `discardChannel="discard.ch"` but, when I set the discard channel, the filtered out messages never seem to actually go to the specified `discardChannel`. Any ideas why this might be?

My @Filter annotated class/method:

```
@Component
public class MessageFilter {

    @Filter(discardChannel = "discard.ch")
    public boolean filter(String payload) {
        // force all messages to be discarded to test discardChannel
        return false;
    }

}
```

My Integration Flow class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class IntegrationConfig {

    @Autowired
    private MessageFilter messageFilter;

    @Bean(name = "discard.ch")
    public DirectChannel discardCh() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow inFlow() {

        return IntegrationFlows
        .from(Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter(mlc)
        .filter("@messageFilter.filter('payload')")
        ...
        .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow discardFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
        .from("discard.ch")
        ...
        .get();
    }
}
```

I have turned on spring debugging on and, I can't see where discarded messages are actually going. It is as though the `discardChannel` I have set on the `@Filter` is not being picked up at all. Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The annotation configuration is for when using annotation-based configuration.

When using the dsl, the annotation is not relevant; you need to configure the `.filter` within the DSL itself...

```
.filter("@messageFilter.filter('payload')", e -> e.discardChannel(discardCh())
```

Comment: Hello Gary, I've configured the discard channel in the DSL code itself as you have suggested and that worked okay. I always seem to get confused between Spring java based annotation configurations and Spring java DSL configurations. Thanks for your help!